# Call function with different arguments type in php

Tags: php, function, laravel, arguments

I need to build a method `column` which can called with different arguments type, such like the situation here .

```
         ->column('herald','style')
         ->column('herald','style','styleText')
         ->column('herald',['kind','style'])
         ->column('herald',['kind','style'],['kindText','styleText'])
         ->column('item',['kind','style'],false)
         ->column('item',['kind','style'],['kindText','styleText'],false)
         ->column('herald_style','style',false)
         ->column('herald_style','style','styleText',false)
```

I just want the function can be called clearly ,to overwrite like the Java do, and I have been tried using the `func_get_args()` to handle the arguments one by one, but it`s seem worse.. 
Is that have any way to do ?

Comment: you may asign a default value in function parameter like function coloumn($a=null,&b=null,$c=null,$d=null){}

Comment: What you meant by the parameter - ['kind','style']?

Comment: i think he wants that the parameter may be an array.@SanjayKumarNS

Comment: @Pradyut Manna Yes I also thinks the same.

Comment: @Fan, can you explain in more details what are you trying to do? This approach seems to be not the best one. What `column()` does?

Comment: @sevavietl method `column()` will handle the collection data we had search, and among them,some column just store the reference code like `a1,b1,c1`,and  we need to formate the code to text

Comment: @Fan, it is better to make `column()` to accept the object, wich you can ask for data `column(Column $column)`. Then you will have different variations of `Column` object you can pass. They all will extend the `Column` object but have different `__construct()` arity. And they must have method `format()`, so you call it inside the `column()` method like this `$text = $column->format()`.

Answer (score 1):

Accepting a variable number of arguments in a function?

If using PHP 5.6+ you can use the splat operator `...` to put any submitted arguments into an array.

```
function column(...$args) {

   // this is how many arguments were submitted
   $number_of_arguments = count($args);

   // iterate through them if you want...
   foreach($args as $arg) {

      // ...and process the arguments one by one
      do_something_with($arg);
   }
}
```

See example 13 on http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

If using an earlier version of PHP then Sanjay Kumar N S's answer will do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean ['kind','style'] as an array, then try this:

```
<?php
function column()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . (!is_array($arg_list[$i]) ? $arg_list[$i]: ' an array ' ). "<br />";
    }
    echo "<br /><br />";
}

column('herald','style');
column('herald','style');
column('herald','style','styleText');
column('herald',array('kind','style'));
column('herald',array('kind','style'),array('kindText','styleText'));
column('item',array('kind','style'),false);
column('item',array('kind','style'),array('kindText','styleText'),false);
column('herald_style','style',false);
column('herald_style','style','styleText',false);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `func_get_args()` at body of your function like this:

```
function callMe() {
    dd(func_get_args());
}
```

Also if it depends on count of arguments you can use `func_num_args()`

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.func-get-args.php